# Mixing Repository implementations for different data sources

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository

A Repository as defined by Martin Fowler is supposed to act like an in-memory domain object collection. This allows the application (in theory) to be ignorant of the persistence mechanism.

So under normal circumstances you'd have something like this:

```
public void MyBusinessLogicMethod () {
    ...
    IRepository<Customer> repository = myIocContainer.Resolve<IRepository<Customer>>();
    repository.Add(customer);
}
```

If however you have a series of inserts/updates that you wish to do and want a mechanism to roll back should any of them fail you'd need some sort of UnitOfWork implementation:

```
public void MyBusinessLogicMethod () {
    ...
    using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork()){
        IRepository<Customer> customerRepo = myIocContainer.Resolve<IRepository<Customer>>(uow);
        customerRepo.Add(customer); 

        IRepository<Order> orderRepo = myIocContainer.Resolve<IRepository<Order>>(uow);
        orderRepo.Add(order); 

        IRepository<Invoice> invoiceRepo = myIocContainer.Resolve<IRepository<Invoice>>(uow);
        invoiceRepo.Update(invoice);

        uow.Save(); 
    }
}
```

However if you had some bizarre requirement that your Customer Repository was acting against a SqlServer database, your Order Repository against a MySql database and your Invoice Repository against a PostgreSQL database, how would you go about handling the Transactions for each database session?

Now this is a bit of contrived example for sure but every Repository implementation I've come across seems to know at some level that it's really a particular database and ORM being used.

Imagine another scenario where you have 2 repositories where one is going to a database and the other is calling a web service. The whole point of Repositories is that the application shouldn't care what data source you are going to but without jumping through some massive hoops I don't see how these scenarios can be accounted for without the application knowing at some level "FYI this is going to data source x so we'd better treat it differently".

Is there a pattern or implementation that addresses this issue? It seems to me if you are using Database x and ORM y for your entire application then Repositories work splendidly, but if due to technical debt that course deviates then the benefits of repositories are greatly reduced.

Comment: I've never had a reason to play with it, but this is supposed to be the problem that [DTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679938.aspx) solves.  Part of the solution is using [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) instead of `ISession.BeginTransaction()`, but that's about as much as I know.

Comment: Yea, TransactionScope is the thing to look at. This is rather a connection and DbConnection implementation thing, all providers must support two phase commit. Nothing to do with nhibernate.

Comment: Interesting. Is there an established way to write your own code so that it will be managed by the TransactionScope? Say if I mocked my repositories to run against collections in memory could I get them to take part in the TransactionScope?

Comment: you would need to write transaction support for this yourself. Use inmemory databases for tests then your test will really test the query execution and the database should implement DTC.

Answer (score 0):

In your UnitOfWork, as suggested, you should use a **TransactionScope** transaction.
It elevates, in your case, to MSDTC and ensure all enlisted operations are correctly executed before commit or otherwise rollback.